# Finding indexOf value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is driving me crazy...
I made an array out of a "getElementsByTagName". Now, by using an onclick where the "this" method returns one of the values of that array, I cannot use "indexOf" to find its index. The console just tells me "arrayThumbs.indexOf is not a function".

This is the code:

```
var arrayThumbs = listThumbs.getElementsByTagName("img"); //Makes the array with the img tags

for(i=0;i<maxFiles-1;i++){
    arrayThumbs[i].onclick = function(){
        imgSelect = this; //Returns a valid value of the array, so far so good
        indexThumb = arrayThumbs.indexOf(imgSelect); //Returns an ERROR...
    };
}
```

The really weird part is that using the same syntax in other arrays this worked perfectly...

Thanks!

Comment: NodeList is not an array

Comment: What object is `arrayThumbs` actually at the point of the error?  Use your browser's debugger to inspect it.

Comment: I believe that `indexOf` need a string value, and that `imgSelect` mayb don't return a string... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo `indexOf` can take anything, not just strings.

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo Note that there are 2 different `.indexOf()` definitions – one [for Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), one [for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). The latter is more-so applicable here and can accept any value. It's ability to match depends on `===`, which requires the types to be the same between the argument and the values within the array.

Comment: I'm learning more everyday... so it's expecting a array, but he uses a NodeList? got it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) which is "array-like" but is not an array and therefore does not have an `indexOf` function. To convert it to an array, you can use `Array.from`, if your browser supports it:

```
arrayThumbs = Array.from(arrayThumbs);
```

Or you can use a well-known trick to convert it to an array:

```
arrayThumbs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayThumbs);
```

Comment: Thought the problem would be something like that...
Thanks!